# Modifying migration column not loaded in migration rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

I added two migration which in the first one I add a column to a model, and in the second one, I execute a function that stores a value into the column recently added of some rows.

The problem is that when I run rake db:migrate the second migration throws an error because the first migration was loaded but the database hasn't changed yet, so one approach is to run the command twice (it works).

First Migration :

```
class AddRegisteredReportToSpecialOfferUse < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :special_offer_uses, :registered_report, :boolean, default: false
  end

  def down
    remove_column :special_offer_uses, :registered_report
  end
end
```

Second Migration :

```
class CreateReportsFromMigrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    OneClass.perform
  end
end
```

the OneClass.perform is a method that makes an update of the attribute added previously

```
def perform
´´´
special_offer_uses.update_attribute(:registered_report, true)
´´´
end
```

The error thrown :

> StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
> undefined method `registered_report=

Note that the method undefined is the name of the attribute added previously.

I wonder if there is a way to avoid running the command twice without throwing any error.

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution using  *reset_column_information* method that causes the columns to be reloaded on the next request.

> Resets all the cached information about columns, which will cause them to be reloaded on the next request.
>
> The most common usage pattern for this method is probably in a migration, when just after creating a table you want to populate it with some default values

Further information : [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class)

Comment: Can you show `error` message?

Comment: i never had that problem. i even do it in the same migration

Comment: Could you put the 2 migrations and the error message

Comment: I added the error as well as the migrations. Let me know if I was clear.

Comment: why is there a space after `special_offer_uses` and it seems like you want to set the new column to true is that right?

Comment: Misspelled and yes it set the new column value to true

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it all in one migration?

```
class AddRegisteredReportToSpecialOfferUse < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :special_offer_uses, :registered_report, :boolean, default: false
    OneClass.perform
  end

  def down
    remove_column :special_offer_uses, :registered_report
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a possible solution. However I am looking for a solution to my issue

Comment: If you insist on having a second migration, try using the `up` method instead of `change`.